# Emulate SSH server for testing purposes

Tags: python, testing, deployment, ssh, fabric

I have to write test for deployment script which uploads files through SSH, but I'd like to have it not depending on external servers configuration. This is how i see it:

1. Create 2 SSH daemons without authentication on different ports of loopback interface.
2. Run the deployment script on these two ports

The only question is how to run these dummy SSH daemons.

I use Python and Fabric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want full control over the server's actions (e.g. in order to simulate various problem conditions and thereby do a really thorough testing) I recommend [twisted](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/SSH-with-Twisted/): as this article shows, it makes it really easy to set up your own custom SSH server.

If you'd rather use an existing ssh server, pick one from the list [here](http://linuxmafia.com/ssh/unix.html) (or use the one that comes with your system, if any; or maybe [sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) if you're on windows) and run it with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/search.html?q=subprocess&check_keywords=yes&area=default) from Python as a part of starting up your tests.

Comment: Thanks for useful idea, but I just monkey patched Fabric API to run all the commands on local server. I'll mark your comment as it has the best solution anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to spin up a dockerized container with sshd service running. You can use a docker image like these:

- https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/fakeserver
- https://github.com/panubo/docker-sshd.

I've used this for testing out a deployment script (made on top of fabric ).

Here's how you use it.

Pull the image.

```
➜ docker pull kabirbaidhya/fakeserver
```

Set authorized keys for the server.

```
➜ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /path/to/authorized_keys
```

Run the fakeserver.

```
➜ docker run -d -p 2222:22 \
             -v "/path/to/authorized_keys:/etc/authorized_keys/tester" \
             -e SSH_USERS="tester:1001:1001" \
             --name=fakeserver kabirbaidhya/fakeserver
```

You can now use the fakeserver from any ssh client. For instance:

```
➜ ssh tester@localhost -p 2222
➜ ssh tester@localhost -p 2222 "echo 'Hello World'"
```

If this works, you can then use any ssh clients or scripts on top of paramiko or fabric to test against this mock server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reimplementing an SSH daemon is not trivial.

If your only problem is you don't want them depending on existing configurations, you can start up new *sshd* with -f to specify a specific configuration and -p to run on a given port.

You can use *os.system* to make calls to the shell:

```
os.system('sshd -f myconfig -p 22022')
```

Comment: This is a great idea and I almost got it working, but I got stuck with ssh-agent which can't run twice with specific authorized_keys file. Anyway, thanks for your response!